# Saved user info in React context, navbar shows logout after login. On navigating to other pages, it displays login instead of logout

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-context

This is the AuthProvider file that I am using to wrap my whole application

```
// AuthContext.tsx
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, ReactNode } from "react";

interface UserData {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  postal: string;
  email: string;
  telephone_number: string;
}

interface AuthContextProps {
  user: UserData | undefined;
  setUser: (userData: UserData | undefined) => void;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserData | undefined>(undefined);

  const updateUser = (userData: UserData | undefined) => {
    setUser(userData);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser: updateUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = (): AuthContextProps => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (!context) { 
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
  }

  return context;
};
```

this is part of the navbar that you will need to check

```
export default function Example() {
  const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  // const { user, setUser } = useAuth();
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <header className="bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-50 via-blue-300 to-blue-500">
        <nav
          className="mx-auto flex max-w-7xl items-center justify-between p-0 lg:px-8"
          aria-label="Global"
        >
          <div className="flex lg:flex-1">
            <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
              <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
              <img
                className="h-8 w-auto"
                src={imgLib}
                alt=""
                style={{ width: "170px", height: "170px" }}
              />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="flex lg:hidden">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="-m-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
              onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(true)}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
              <Bars3Icon
                className="h-6 w-6 mr-5"
                aria-hidden="true"
                style={{ color: "white" }}
              />
            </button>
          </div>
          <Popover.Group className="hidden lg:flex lg:gap-x-12">
            <a
              href="/home"
              className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-black-900"
            >
              Home
            </a>
            <a
              href="/about"
              className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-black-900"
            >
              About us
            </a>
            <a
              href="/contact"
              className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-black-900"
            >
              Contact
            </a>
            <a className="dropdown">
              <a
                className="dropbtn"
                style={{ color: "black", fontWeight: "550" }}
              >
                Library
                <i className="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </a>
              <div className="dropdown-content">
                <a href="/library">Book store</a>
                <a href="/meeting-room">Meeting room</a>
                <a href="/book-table">My books</a>
              </div>
            </a>
          </Popover.Group>
          <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:flex-1 lg:justify-end">
            {context?.user === undefined ? (
              <a
                href="/"
                className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-black-900"
              >
                Log in <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
              </a>
            ) : (
              <a
                onClick={() => context.setUser(undefined)}
                href="/"
                className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-black-900"
              >
                Log out <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
              </a>
              // access the username here
            )}
```

this is my app being wrapped

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./pages/Login.tsx";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup.tsx";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home.tsx";
import socket from "./Socket.tsx";
import { NotificationProvider } from "./context/NotificationProvider.tsx";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.tsx";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthProvider.tsx";

// import './styles/About.css'
// import './styles/Library.css'
// import './styles/Home.css'
// import './styles/myBooks.css'
//meeting-room
import About from "./pages/About.tsx";
import Library from "./pages/Library.tsx";
import BookTable from "./components/BookTable.tsx";
import MeetingRoomsPage from "./pages/BookingRoomsPage.tsx";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact.tsx";
import ReserveRooms from "./pages/ReservedRooms.tsx";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  
  <BrowserRouter>
    
      <NotificationProvider />
      <AuthProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login></Login>}></Route>
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup></Signup>}></Route>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About></About>}></Route>
        <Route path="/library" element={<Library></Library>}></Route>
        <Route path="/book-table" element={<BookTable></BookTable>}></Route>
        <Route path="/meeting-room" element={<MeetingRoomsPage></MeetingRoomsPage>}></Route>
        <Route path="/reserver-rooms" element={<ReserveRooms></ReserveRooms>}></Route>
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact></Contact>}></Route>
      </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
 
   
  </BrowserRouter>
  
);
```

I just tried to console log in the other pages where the option of log in return and I found that the context becomes undefined when navigating to other pages. It should be defined with user info so that the option of log in never go away unless I log out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When navigating through `<a/>` element it causes the page to refresh, leading to the resetting of the context. a possible solution would be to use `<Link/>` element from the `"react-router-dom"` instead of the `<a/>` to prevent the page from refreshing, like changing this:

```
<a href="/home" className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-black-900">Home</a>
```

to this:

```
<Link to="/home" className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-black-900">Home</Link>
```

and the same for the others.

A better solution would be to store the data you don't want to lose in browser cookies or local storage and load it once the website opens using `useEffect`.

an Example using local storage, assuming you call `updateUser` whenever the use log in, change it to:

```
  const updateUser = (userData: UserData | undefined) => {
    if(userData == undefined) localStorage.removeItem("userData")
    else localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(userData))
    setUser(userData);
  };
;
```

and use `useEffect` hook to get the data back from the local storage once the page reloads:

```
export const AuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserData | undefined>(undefined);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem("userData");
    if (storedData) {
      const parsedData: UserData = JSON.parse(storedData);
      setUser(parsedData);
    }
  }, [])
};
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I changed from a tag to Link and now it works. but what is the point of storing it locally after publishing the website?

Comment: @YousefAlsakkaf glad it helped,  So as you noticed, the context becomes undefined when the page refreshes, which causes the user to log out. In order to keep the user logged in, you can store their data in the local storage of their browser. This way, the data persists across sessions and reloads. - assuming you are handling the auth token -